# Clear form after submit and disable form in angular service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I create a service to upload content.
it takes 4 argument

- which folder to update
- the content
- set the form to disabled
- clear form after submit

  ```
  create: function(folderID, text, o, master) {
      o.isDisabled = true;
          ob = {
              text: text,
              media: 'Pending',
              createdBy: $rootScope.AUTH.user.uid,
              createdTime: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
          };
          _firebaseRef.files.child(folderID).push(ob, function(error) {                       $timeout(function() {
              if (error) {
                  alert('Create file failed, please try again');                          o.isDisabled = false;
              } else {
                  o.isDisabled = false;
                  angular.copy(master, o);
              };
          });
      });
  },
  ```

So when in controller.

`service.create(folderID, 'hello world', $scope.file, $scope.master);`

**My question**

How can I omit the 3rd and 4th arguments?

Comment: Why would you want to omit those arguments?

Comment: In controller reset model used for `ng-model`. Set form pristine and can use `ng-disabled` on submit button based on `$invalid`

Comment: @Beyers i just want to omit in controller. So it still in service, just I don't need to pass the args in controller

Comment: @charlietfl any example code or demo?

Comment: start here  http://docs.angularjs.org/cookbook/advancedform

Comment: create demo in plunker with simple  form and a controller if want more help